# Multiple virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions, overriding, virtual-inheritance

I know there are many questions out there concerning MI, however, none seemed to answer my question. I have the following minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
struct A : public virtual Base{
    void foo(){
        std::cout << "A::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
    void foo( int a){
        std::cout << "A::foo(int a)" << std::endl;
    }
};
struct B : public virtual Base{
    virtual void foo( int a ) = 0;
};
struct C : public B,public A{
    using A::foo;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[]){
    C c;
    c.foo();
    c.foo( 1 );
}
```

where Base, and B are entirely virtual classes and A provides all the implementation. However, the code does not compile but instead gives me the following error message

```
mh.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
mh.cpp:22:11: error: cannot declare variable ‘c’ to be of abstract type ‘C’
     C c;
       ^
mh.cpp:17:12: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘C’:
 struct C : public B,public A{
        ^
mh.cpp:15:22: note:     virtual void B::foo(int)
     virtual void foo( int a ) = 0;
```

The behaviour I desire can be achieved by extending class `C` to

```
struct C : public B,public A{
    using A::foo;
    void foo( int a ){
        A::foo( a );
    }
};
```

However, I'd prefer not adding this redundant method. Is there some way I can achieve that result?

Comment: Can you add `virtual void foo( int a) = 0;` to `Base`?

Comment: I recommend using the new `override` specifier available in C++11 everywhere you think you are overriding a virtual function. It makes problems like this easier to find.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought I could use virtual classes the way I can use interfaces in Java. I realized I cannot and will update my design accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A::foo(int)` can't override `B::foo(int)` unless `A` derives from `B`.

So, if you don't want to create the forwarding override in `C`, your alternatives are:

1. move the `foo(int)` pure virtual overload into `Base`
2. make `A` derive from `B`
3. restructure your interfaces so you don't need diamond-shaped virtual inheritance in the first place

Comment: I think I have to use a different structure altogether in that case. What's bothering me is that the very same structure can be easily realized in Java using interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you inherit from a pure virtual class and you want to use this derived class (declare object of that type, not a pointer), you must implement all its pure virtual methods. 
In the same manner you could ask the following:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void foo()=0;
    virtual void hello()=0;
}

class B: public A
{
public:
    void myFoo();
    void hello() { std::cout << "Hello!"; }
}
```

*In `class B`, I don't want to use `A::foo()` but only `B::myFoo()` what should I do?*

In such case you either need to provide some dummy implementation for the pure virtual function or review again your design... probably you should not inherit from A.

Similar thing is in your case. Probably your `class C` should not inherit from `class B`.

Answer (score 0):

- Just replace your single line as below.
- Derived **C** only from **A**.
- Your code

  ```
  struct C : public B,public A{
  using A::foo;
  };
  ```
- Replace above code with below code,

  ```
  struct C : public A{
  using A::foo;
  };
  ```

Comment: unfortunately I cannot cast C to B in that case